# React: context hook, push object into an array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The error I'm getting is `Cannot find name 'objectArray'.`

```
interface StateInterface {
  objects: {
    objectArray: object[];
    selected: object;
  };
}

const InitialState: StateInterface = {
  objects: {
    objectArray: [],
    selected: {},
  },
};


const Reducer = (state: StateInterface, action: any) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SELECTED':
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: { ...state.objects, selected: action.value },
      };
    case 'ADD_OBJECT':
      return {
        ...state,
        objects: { ...state.objects, objectArray: objectArray.push(action.value )},
//                                                     ^---- Cannot find name 'objectArray'.ts(2304)
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I also tried

```
objects: { ...state.objects, objectArray:  ...action.value )},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the state object is in scope at that point (provided as an argument to the reducer), try switching `objectArray` for `state.objectArray` at the point you're getting the error.

But also, you'll need to append the value immutably for it to be correct (a rule of reducers), so you'll need to make that whole line something like:

`objects: { ...state.objects, objectArray: [...state.objectArray, action.value]},`

To create a new array with both the old values and the new value you're adding.

Comment: objects: { ...state.objects, objectArray: [...state.objects.objectArray, action.value]}, did the trick thank you